# Partial refunds in Exp:resso Store

Tags: expressionengine, expresso-store

Is there any way to process a partial refund from Exp:resso Store? I periodically need to credit a return of just a single item out of the order, and haven't been able to figure out how to do that. Or, failing to do it all through the CP, could I process the refund through Stripe (my payment processor) and then just remove the item from the order or tag it as "refunded" (for consistent records)?

Comment: Hey Eli - since this isn't a technical question so much a software usage question, it doesn't really belong on StackOverflow. ([See FAQ.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions)) Best to consult the developers of this add-on for support on this one.

Comment: @DerekHogue we're encouraging people to post here to build up their rep until the EE site launches. I'm lurking and happy to answer the questions. I realize this particular question is slightly off topic for Stack Overflow - hence why we need a dedicated site!

Comment: @Adrian - yes, but we shouldn't be ignoring (or encouraging others to ignore) SO's posting guidelines in the process.

Comment: I think closing was a bit over the top though - by that standard all questions which only involve the EE CP (importing/exporting data, installation issues, MSM, etc) should all be closed because they are software usage and not programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible using the CP, and some gateways don't support partial refunds anyway. However, I'm pretty sure Stripe does, so the best solution is to do it through the Stripe website.

To reconcile things with your store, you can either make a `Partially Refunded` status, or you can simply add a manual payment to the order with a negative amount (however this will make the order show up as "Unpaid").

Comment: Thanks, Adrian. This doesn't really help me, since I need to run reports of who bought a particular item (hey, I didn't write VZ Buyers for nothing!) and there's no way currently to tell there which items have been returned. Can I make a feature request for statuses on individual line-items? That would make situations like this much more manageable, as well as things like partial-order shipments.

Comment: Sure. I think we should keep feature requests of SO so happy to email you about it. Line item level refunds would be nice though.